# Copy background from one element to another using jQuery not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

Here's a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XcC5d/1/

```
$('.select').on('click', function(event){
    $('.result').css('background', $(event.target).css('background'));
});
```

When clicking on any of the first 3 .select divs, it copies the background css value and sets it to the result with the red border.

This works in safari and chrome but not in firefox.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('.select').on('click', function(event){
    $('.result').css('background', $(event.target).css('background-image'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the background-image property of the CSS.
Like this: [Update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcC5d/3/)

```
$('.select').on('click', function(event){
    $('.result').css('background', $(event.target).css('background-image'));
});
```

Edit: Damn, few seconds too late :)