# copy background-image from one div to another

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple divs that may be considered as buttons with different background-image and css file with styles like:

```
#button1 { background-image: url('../images/abc.png) }
#button2 { background-image: url('../images/def.png) }
#button3 { background-image: url('../images/ghi.png) }
```

Each button also is part of class .button.

I also have a div with class "popup". If I click any button it has added new class: isActive.

I want to read background-image of button that has "isActive" class and put it to "popup" div.

I wanted to do sth like this with jQuery:

```
var bg;
bg = $('.isActive').css('background-image')
console.log(bg)
$('.popup').css('background-image', bg )
```

Unfortunately, console.log returns bg that contains:

> file:///C:/Users/me/projects/images/abc.png

is there an elegant way to copy not full path with "file://" and so on, just "../images/abc.png", as I defined in css?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do this? The file path you retrieve using JS is the resolved, absolute path of a relative path, and it should work just as fine if you want to use it as-is.

Comment: `"../images"+bg.split("images")[1]` - and I guess you want `$('.popup').css('background-image', "url("+bg +")")`

Comment: @terry i am aware of why this is happening, just want to know how to solve it

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681646/copy-background-from-one-element-to-another-using-jquery-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: That was it Shimon. Please copy that answer to your post below and i will accept this answet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a css class with each background. Then you will be able to assign to popup whatever background you want.

```
.bgr1 { background-image: url('../images/abc.png) }
.bgr2 { background-image: url('../images/def.png) }
.bgr3 { background-image: url('../images/ghi.png) }
```

And then assign:

```
var allClasses = ['bgr1', 'bgr2', 'bgr3'];
var bgr = $('.isActive').attr('class').split(' ').filter(cls=>allClasses.indexOf(cls) > -1).shift();
if (bgr)
    $('.popup').addClass(ngr);
```

### Update

taken from here: [Copy background from one element to another using jQuery not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681646/copy-background-from-one-element-to-another-using-jquery-not-working-in-firefox]):

```
$('.popup').css('background', $('.isActive').css('background-image'));
```

Comment: That is not a good idea because there is a lot more than just three backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

You may found your solution here: [Get BackgroundImage](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-background-image)

```
$(this).css('background-image');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Your js code src (source) is relative to your html/php file and not to your js file.